# Change HTML on includes on each page

Tags: php, html

I have my website, for example with this layout:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>

<!-- CONTENT -->

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Now, on each page, for example: `home`, `contact`, `about us`, etc, I have to add a class `active` to the menu. But since I have just one file with the header, how can I change some HTML in each single page?

Thanks, and sorry if this was asked before, I can't find this anywhere, and I don't know how to search for it.

Comment: using  create two header files?

Comment: if I create two header files I repeat some code and the goal I try to achieve is to minimize the amount of changes I have to do each time I change something in the menu

Answer (score 0):

Say, you 3 pages.

Get them in an array in `header.php`.

```
$pages = array();
$pages['home'] = 'Home';
$pages['about-us'] = 'About Us';
$pages['contact'] = 'Contact Us';
```

Show menu like and get current page parameter:

If the parameter matches your page, show active class.

```
<ul>
<?php
$current = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
if (! empty($pages)) {
 foreach ($pages as $url => $title) {
  $active = ($current == $page) ? 'active' : '';
  // Observe, the class 'active', main logic is here.
?>
 <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $url;?>" class="<?php echo $active;?>"><?php echo $title;?></a></li>
<?php
 }
}
?>
</ul>
```